# What is the definition of hull voltage?

Tags: safety

I'm studying the subject *Electrical Safety in Engineering* and a special term really drew my attention. When I tried to google it, no any option was suggested but ***hull protection***.

---

In the presentation slide, the definition of the term is explained in a such way.

---

> **Hull voltage**: voltage that occurs when the insulation between
>   accessible contacting parts usually not under voltage and a sufficiently
>   distant point on the Earth's surface, is damaged or between such parts
>   and other conductive parts with zero potential;
>
> ---

Could anyone explain the exact meaning of the term **hull voltage**?

Comment: google for 'cathodic protection'. Hull voltage is almost certainly to do with electrochemical corrosion where you have different metals in contact with seawater. As for what it means *exactly*, that's to do with exactly how it's defined in any circumstance. Different reference electrodes will give you different hull voltages.

Comment: You may find that you should contact your lecturer / professor or the person who wrote that to be sure what they meant.

Comment: That definition is, charitably, hard to read.